# Why does Doxygen not generate any documentation for this?

Tags: c, doxygen

I have the following directory structure:

```
.cache
.direnv
.git
.vscode
doc
.envrc
.gitignore
3darr.c
Doxyfile
Makefile
compile_commands.json
flake.lock
flake.nix
```

I generated `Doxyfile` with `doxywizard` and manual editing.

`Doxyfile` reads:

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = 3darr
PROJECT_NUMBER         =
PROJECT_BRIEF          =
PROJECT_LOGO           =
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = doc
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
CREATE_SUBDIRS_LEVEL   = 8
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        =
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    =
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
JAVADOC_BANNER         = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
PYTHON_DOCSTRING       = YES
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_SLICE  = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      =
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 5
MARKDOWN_ID_STYLE      = DOXYGEN
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
NUM_PROC_THREADS       = 1
TIMESTAMP              = NO
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
RESOLVE_UNNAMED_PARAMS = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = SYSTEM
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_HEADERFILE        = YES
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       =
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    =
LAYOUT_FILE            =
CITE_BIB_FILES         =
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_IF_INCOMPLETE_DOC = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_IF_UNDOC_ENUM_VAL = NO
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LINE_FORMAT       = "at line $line of file $file"
WARN_LOGFILE           =
INPUT                  = .
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
INPUT_FILE_ENCODING    =
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.l \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08 \
                         *.f18 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf \
                         *.ice
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                =
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       =
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        =
EXAMPLE_PATH           =
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             =
INPUT_FILTER           =
FILTER_PATTERNS        =
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS =
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE =
FORTRAN_COMMENT_AFTER  = 72
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
IGNORE_PREFIX          =
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            =
HTML_FOOTER            =
HTML_STYLESHEET        =
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  =
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       =
HTML_COLORSTYLE        = AUTO_LIGHT
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_DYNAMIC_MENUS     = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_FEEDURL         =
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               =
HHC_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     =
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
SITEMAP_URL            =
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               =
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   =
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHG_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
FULL_SIDEBAR           = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
OBFUSCATE_EMAILS       = YES
HTML_FORMULA_FORMAT    = png
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_MACROFILE      =
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_VERSION        = MathJax_2
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        =
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     =
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       =
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       =
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     =
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  =
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         =
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
LATEX_MAKEINDEX_CMD    = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         =
LATEX_HEADER           =
LATEX_FOOTER           =
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET =
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      =
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
LATEX_EMOJI_DIRECTORY  =
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    =
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    =
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             =
MAN_LINKS              = NO
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
XML_NS_MEMB_FILE_SCOPE = NO
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
GENERATE_SQLITE3       = NO
SQLITE3_OUTPUT         = sqlite3
SQLITE3_RECREATE_DB    = YES
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX =
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           =
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  =
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
TAGFILES               =
GENERATE_TAGFILE       =
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_COMMON_ATTR        = "fontname=Helvetica,fontsize=10"
DOT_EDGE_ATTR          = "labelfontname=Helvetica,labelfontsize=10"
DOT_NODE_ATTR          = "shape=box,height=0.2,width=0.4"
DOT_FONTPATH           =
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
DOT_UML_DETAILS        = NO
DOT_WRAP_THRESHOLD     = 17
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DIR_GRAPH_MAX_DEPTH    = 1
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               =
DOTFILE_DIRS           =
DIA_PATH               =
DIAFILE_DIRS           =
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      =
PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      =
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  =
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
MSCGEN_TOOL            =
MSCFILE_DIRS           =
```

And `3darr.c` begins:

```c
/**
 * @file 3darr.h
 * Code comprising the `3darr` program.
 * Unless specified otherwise, all functions have the implicit precondition of
 * all their arguments being defined. Unless specified otherwise, all functions
 * taking pointers have the implicit precondition that these pointers are valid,
 * and their pointees, if they are pointers, also satisfy the property the
 * argument itself satisfies. If an effect is not qualified by "may" or does not
 * express a mere possibility, it is guaranteed.
 */

#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * Element of our array.
 * The fact that this is a unsigned long is relied on.
 */
typedef unsigned long elem;
```

…but Doxygen writes none of these into the documentation unless I enable `EXTRACT_ALL`!

What’s going on?

Comment: I could imagine the reason Doxygen does this, is because your typedef is in a `C`file and not a header file. That would mean the compiler would likely mark this `static` or private to the TU context. Enabling `EXTRACT_ALL` would mean it also retrieves private members

Comment: What constitutes a private member? I have not included the full file but it contains more functions. Also, they do not get extracted even if I enable `EXTRACT_PRIVATE`.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Why do you have `@file 3darr.h` in your `3darr.c` file, now this comment block is intended to document (out of place) the `3darr.h` file (that does not exist, and emits a warning `3darr.c:2: warning: the name '3darr.h' supplied as the argument in the \file statement is not an input file`). Regarding the code files doxygen likes to have some sort of documentation of the file itself (e.g. either through its own `\@file` or through the `EXTRACT_ALL`).

Comment: @SimonC by default private members are excluded by doxygen unless you set `EXTRAC_PRIVATE=YES` (similar accounts for static members, here you need `EXTRACT_STATIC`).

Comment: Oh, that might be the issue. The @file is supposed to say `3darr.c`.